# Kid’s TV cartoon show (2000s) involving a group and the 4 elements

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I’m trying to find the name of an animated show I used to watch, but can’t see it on any Wikipedia or online lists.

I think it was set in Asia, and it was about a group who could use elements like fire and water to fight. I remember one of the girls transformed to gain stripes and eyes like a tiger, and other members of the group gained characteristics of other animals.

Comment: Is it Captain Planet and the Planeteers? An environmentalist superhero group with the powers of Earth, Wind, Fire, Water and Heart.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiYjTb3opAA

Comment: Don't recall them gaining animal traits on Captain Planet.

Comment: Possibly not. I've never seen it. Just suggested a possibility, with the element powers.

Comment: Do you know what network you watched it on? Did it look realistic? Cartoony? Super-deformed? Do you think it was originally in English?

Comment: *Xiaolin Showdown* doesn't seem to hae animal transformations

Comment: Consider browsing through this list: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FourElementEnsemble

Comment: “who could use elements like fire and water to fight” — not *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, I take it?